# Why is there a "dwThreadId" and a "dwProcessId" for a newly created process via CreateProcess in win32 API programming?

Tags: windows, winapi, createprocess

I'm curious why there are two separate IDs - `dwProcessId` and `dwThreadId` returned in the `PROCESS_INFORMATION` data structure when I call `CreateProcess` in win32 API programming?

In what cases would I use the `dwThreadId`? So far I haven't found a use case. I only use the process id to identify the program that I started via `CreateProcess`.

Also I'm very curious why does Linux have just a `pid` (aka ProcessId) but Windows has both pid and threadid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every process has at least one thread. The thread id gives you the id of the first thread created for a process by the CreateProcess API. You can create more threads and they'd have id's too.

They're separate only because process ids are for processes and thread ids are for threads. I don't think there's much more to say about it!

Comment: Can you compare that to Linux? Linux also has a thread for the created process but it only returns the processId.

Comment: Just linux doesn't return you the thread id in the API, because the person who wrote the API didn't think it was important... you can probably find it via some other API. The person who came up with the windows API probably had the thread Id, and thought, I know, I'll return that from CreateProcess just in case anybody happens to want it, then they won't have to call a separate API to find out what it is.

Comment: Oh wow. Thanks for the explanation. I'd have never thought of it.

Comment: Yeh, it's just what the designer of the API thought would be convenient for users of it. Just like my kettle has the on off switch below the handle, but some designers put the switch above the handle. They both work fine and do the same thing, but are different. :)

Answer (score 0):

Created process has threads, because any process has at least one thread. So creating a process you also create its first thread of execution, and the API function get you both at once.

You use thread identifiers when you need to lookup certain thread, and you use process identifier where your called function or API expect an identifier of a process. You are unlikely to stumble on anything that takes both and you are in doubt which of the identifiers to hand in there.

Comment: Can you compare that to Linux? Linux also has a thread for the created process but it only returns the processId.

Comment: [Linux](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettid): In a single-threaded process, the thread ID is equal to the process ID (PID, as returned by getpid(2)). In a multithreaded process, all threads have the same PID, but each one has a unique TID.

Comment: The point is that there both worlds have identifiers for both processes and threads. Linux starts with assigning the same identifier to new process and its first thread, hence no need to return two identifiers. Still PID/TID values have pretty much the same meaning.

Comment: Linux didn't have threads until version 2.6 so the API, which is older, would naturally not return a thread ID.  In Windows, the thread ID is needed by debuggers and I suspect that's why CreateProcess returns it.